# QML Access a Component using a string to reference it´s ID

Tags: qt, qml

Here is the thing. I need to do the same processing for 16 Custom Input Boxes. This is a drag. So I thought I could add their ids to some sort of list and then iterate through a list, calling on a fucntion that does the processing.

Problem is I don't know how to access the component (to get the inputted text and set some variables inside it) when the id is in a string variable. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving an answer here, in case it is of any help to anyone. 
As it turns out you can just pass the input element as a parameter to a function. So lets say that you have

```
TextInput{
   id: input1
   ...
} 

TextInput{
   id: input2
   ...
}
```

You could do this:

```
var list = [input1, input2]
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) doStuffFunction(list[i])
```

And inside the function...

```
function doStuffFunction (imp){
   var thetext = imp.text
   //... Do more stuff
}
```